# if (($strUsers == "") && false) ? what the false is referring to?

Tags: php, dreamweaver

Here is a function from Dreamweaver, if (($strUsers == "") && false) what the false is referring to? in what case it is a TRUE, and in what case it is a FALSE ?
Thank you.

```
function isAuthorized($strUsers, $strGroups, $UserName, $UserGroup) { 
  // For security, start by assuming the visitor is NOT authorized. 
  $isValid = False; 

  // When a visitor has logged into this site, the Session variable MM_Username set equal to their username. 
  // Therefore, we know that a user is NOT logged in if that Session variable is blank. 
  if (!empty($UserName)) { 
    // Besides being logged in, you may restrict access to only certain users based on an ID established when they login. 
    // Parse the strings into arrays. 
    $arrUsers = Explode(",", $strUsers); 
    $arrGroups = Explode(",", $strGroups); 
    if (in_array($UserName, $arrUsers)) { 
      $isValid = true; 
    } 
    // Or, you may restrict access to only certain users based on their username. 
    if (in_array($UserGroup, $arrGroups)) { 
      $isValid = true; 
    } 
    if (($strUsers == "") && false) { 
      $isValid = true; 
    } 
  } 
  return $isValid; 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting from [a forum](http://www.phpfreaks.com/forums/index.php?topic=86601.0):

> Likewise the following line of code: if (($strUsers == "") && false) {
> contains true or false accordingly and this is what actually controls
> whether user has access or not. So, if I am right then the 'false' in
> the above satement could be replaced with the variable
> $MM_donotCheckaccess - this would make the code easier to read and
> make use of the variable. Otherwise it seems to be entirely redundant!

Also, this makes this block NEVER run. It seems if you set to true, a blank user can login or anyone can login if there's no user, I don't know what does it actually stand for, but from the name one of the mentioned 2 possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like an error to me. Because of that false, that if statement will always be false, so `$isValid = true;` should never get executed. You should recheck the logic that you are trying to accomplish with this code, because it seems confusing at best, and simple incorrect at worst.

Comment: I meant the last IF condition: if (($strUsers == "") && false). what the false is referring to ? Many thanks.

Comment: It was probably an error that was introduced at some point. It makes no sense anymore. Perhaps a developer temporarily introduced it during debugging (to force that if to always be false), but forgot to take it out.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen that done as a means of temporarily disabling a check (usually for testing / debugging purposes). It was probably left in. I'm not saying that's a good idea just that seems why you'd come across code like that.

Answer (score 0):

It's used by Dreamweaver as something that it can easily replace depending on the settings you specify when you initially go through Dreamweaver's setup - it will place either `true` or `false` there depending on whether or not you told it to actually check access.

Answer (score 0):

False referring nothing, you want only below condition for checking.

```
if ($strUsers == "")
```

Comment: In that case a "blank" user will be able to login, so no, you *don't* want it unless you're only testing